# How to replace the fuse for both indicators on a Nissan Wingroad 2004?

Tags: electrical, nissan, fuse, towing, indicators

While towing a borrowed trailer yesterday, my indicators stopped working. The noise usually made by them turning on and off also stopped, and the lights for the indicators in the dashboard stopped working too.

The headlights and tail lights still work. The hazard lights also work (both on the dashboard and the actual lights themselves).

I figure it's probably a blown fuse, but looking at the available fuses I can't see one for the indicators. I've attached photos of the fusebox and another fuseboxy looking thing that I could find.

[image: fusebox by battery, with cover removed and to the side]

[image: another fusebox?]

I tried removing the 10A fuses labelled ECCS and TAIL LAMP in the top photo to see if they had blown but they look fine. Can anyone tell me which fuse is for the indicators, or whether I'm completely barking down the wrong track?

Comment: I'm thinking, from your description, that the problem is the blinker relay, not a fuse. The lights themselves should go through the tail lamp fuse. The relay is what gives the charachteristic ticking sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking, from your description, that the problem is the blinker relay, not a fuse. The lights themselves should go through the tail lamp fuse. The relay is what gives the characteristic ticking sound. The emergency flashers usually run off of a separate blinker relay, but may be the same thing. If so, you can use it to test between the two. These relays are usually located under the dash.

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice! This answer fits very well with everything that's happening. I took it to a local auto electrician, and they fixed it for NZ$10, which was surprisingly cheap. Unfortunately I can't confirm exactly what the issue was, as the person who did the work was out to lunch when I picked it up.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular ... That sounds about right for the cost of the part ... they must have done the diagnostic and physical replacement for free. Glad it's fixed for you!